# history.pushState() causing browser navigation

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the URL of a page without navigating the browser to that page and causing a refresh. In the [MDN documentation for manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries), it states the following:

> Suppose http://mozilla.org/foo.html executes the following JavaScript:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");
```

> This will cause the URL bar to display http://mozilla.org/bar.html, but won't cause the browser to load bar.html or even check that bar.html exists.

This seems to be corroborated by everyone on StackOverflow as well. However, in my code, `window.history.pushState()` is navigating the page. The console even states quite clearly:

```
Navigated to http://localhost:8090/?
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
attemptLogin(username, password)
  .then((result) => {
    // navigate to Landing Page
    window.history.pushState('data', 'title', '/');
  })
```

I'm also not sure why it's adding a question mark, but the fact that it is navigating the browser seems like the more pressing issue. Does anyone have any insight they could offer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have provided will not cause the effect you have described.

You are triggering that code *somehow*. The symptoms you have say that it is from an event such as a click on a link or a submission of a form.

The JavaScript is running, and then the normal behaviour of the link or form submission is occurring … which is to cause the browser to navigate to a new URL.

You need to prevent the default behaviour of that action, for example:

```
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", handler);

function handler(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    attemptLogin(username, password)
        .then((result) => {
                    window.history.pushState('data', 'title', '/');
        });
}
```

Comment: That MDN page looks quite wrong to me, in particular that quoted sentence in the OP. Calling `.pushState()` *does* cause a GET for the new page as its default action, right?

Comment: @Pointy — No. The whole point of `pushState` is that is changes the URL without making an HTTP request. It is there so you can use client-side JS to change the DOM and update the URL to one that reflects the new state of the page (so you can bookmark it and come back later, or share a link with a friend, or go back and forward).

Comment: Hmm.. that _almost_ seems like the solution, since I am using a form submit to trigger this. However, I find that when I remove the line `window.history.pushState('data', 'title', '/');` and just replace it with a console log or something else, I do not get the browser navigation effect. Why would that be?

Comment: @Marisha — Perhaps something about it is throwing an exception which breaks something else. It's hard to identify the cause of the problem when there isn't a [mcve].

Comment: Ah OK; it causes a state change *event* then. I was confused because I have entire single-page applications based on this :)  But I do it all via the "statechange" events, after reviewing the code I wrote 4 years ago.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you for directing me to that page, I will be sure to use it in the future. I think the issue is I just haven't researched form event propagation enough, because `preventDefault()` does resolve my issue. So thank you!